# My mom is the only person who noticed it vs my mom has been the only person who noticed it

Tags: grammar

So I've lost 11 pounds and no one actually noticed the difference except my mum. In this case, do I have to say

> My mom is the only person who noticed it

Or

> My mom has been the only person who noticed it so far

Which one is correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think one is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about an **overall period**, like no one has ever noticed this and neither do you expect anyone to notice it anymore after all this time, you'd choose the first option, i.e. "My mom is the only person who noticed it".

But, if you're talking about a **specific period**, like it's been a week or a month, you would choose the second sentence, "My mom has been the only person who noticed it so far".
(Like, "It's been a month, and my mom has been the only person who noticed it so far.)